# Mount NFS Share in Kodi on Android TV

Tags: android-tv

I have a Sony Bravia Android TV. Has anyone managed to mount an NFS share in the Kodi media center app? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I did, but not directly through NFS, but through Samba / SMB instead. But, since you have already figure this thing out then there is no point to follow this discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. One needs to add the insecure option on the server side,

`/mnt/MOUNTPOINT IP (ro,no_subtree_check,insecure)`

works on my system.